Storage Type / Bucket in GCP
I am creating an online library, and I have thought that the thousands of books that I want to incorporate
are saved in a Bucket in GCP.
When creating the Bucket, I must choose between the options that I show in the image, the Standard option seems to be
the appropriate one for mentioning "frequently accessed data" but it also says "For short-term storage" which is what is confusing.

I don't want the books uploaded to the Bucket to be deleted after a while, then the web service would go down.
Any recommendations or clarification of terms that you can suggest to me?


I don't want the books uploaded to the Bucket to be deleted after a while

That won't happen with any of the choices you see.  What you're being asked is to choose a storage class, which determines the cost and overall performance of reading the objects out of the bucket.  I suggest reading that linked documentation so you understand the result of the choice you're making.
If you intend to read the data frequently and not leave it for archival purposes, then you probably want the standard option. But you need to make this decision yourself based on your project's requirements.
